# What would be the best mechanism to rotate a plate from 0 to 15 degrees?

Tags: motors, design, servo, machine-design

I'm designing a machine in a small university project that change position of a two-state gate. The two states shown in the Figure below are 0 and 17 degrees of elevation, correspondingly. The dimensions of the gate are `L= 300 mm.` and `thickness=3 mm.`. Also, the gate's material is Aluminium 6061. Other component's materials are steel stainless 304.The gate is not going to suppor any weight neither other forces, just their own weight.

[image: isometric view]

I was thinking on a servomotor directly connected to the axis of the gate, but I'm concerned if a servomotor can work with the following operational characteristics:

- Change the state in less than 1 second. Work, a petition but for 6 hours. (Is not going to change each 1 second, 2 in average). So, we can say that is going to change state 10k times in 6 hours, approximately.
- Change from 0 to 15 degrees and vice versa.
- There's no electrical restrictions.
- There's no limit of motor dimensions.

[image: mechanism]
[image: gate]

Also, one frind suggest me to change the pivot place and use mechanism like the Figure below.

[image: mechanism 2]

I'm looking for suggestions and recommendations for this design. I'll really appreaciate all your ideas and learn from the feedback!

Comment: A linear servo?

Comment: I agree with your friend, but would use a stepper motor, rather than a 'simple motor', by which I assume you were thinking DC brushed?

Comment: SolarMike Also can works better than the my first idea. @JonathanRSwift I update the image, and yes I was thinking on a DC Motor ("Simple motor"). So, now a stepper motor and a linear servomotor as alternatives, I'm going to check properties of which one can be the best. Thank guys.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally go with Magnetic actuators, as those are highly reliable and can flip between their states extremely fast. As they are providing linear motion in a rather short range, you would need some lever on the hinge, but the part itself can be the hinge.

Most magnetic actuators also have a rather small build volume, so the actuator might even be mounted inside the machine. The main benefit however is the ease of flipping states and modifying the interval simply by activating the coils - which is as easy as putting a positive signal onto the coil or the relay that supplies it.